# Complexity of existence of m-cycle in planar graph with n nodes

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, planar-graph

G is a planar graph with n nodes.
What are the complexity of following problems?

1. A: Does G contain a m-cycle? (m-cycle is a simple cycle with m nodes, m

   B: complexity of counting all m-cycles in G.

   what is the complexity of A and B if G is an arbitrary given graph?

Pointing to books and papers is also useful...

Comment: Have you seen this discussion on MathOverflow?

  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35453/finding-all-cycles-of-a-certain-length-in-a-graph

Comment: Useful link, thanks. but there is all about bound on the number of cycles and I'm looking for the complexity of counting such cycles!:(